# polylang + category/tag custom language link

Tags: plugins, categories, customization, multi-language, plugin-polylang

under wordpress user can define url part for categories/tags, e.g., page.com/category/some-cat where category is user defined string part.
Is there a way to define "category" (same goes for tags) for multilanguage page, so that for en category=categoryen, for ru category=kategorij, etc?
As a results links should be page.com/categoryen and page.com/kategorij.
Any ideas if this is just a configuration task, or requires extensive programming?